# SwiperJS shows 5 posts/slides instead of 3, despite having slidesPerView: 3 - Wordpress, Genesis Featured Posts widget, swiperJS

Tags: wordpress, swiper.js, genesis

I'm trying to make a SwiperJS slider using the Genesis Featured Post widget.
I'd like the slider to show 3 out of a total of 5 posts.

*The Problem*
The slider shows all 5 posts, despite setting slidesPerView: 3

*Swiper Initialization Code*

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {

          spaceBetween: 30,

           slidesPerView: 3,

           autoplay:false,
     
          pagination: {

            el: '.swiper-pagination',

            clickable: true,
          },

          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',

          },
       });
```

*Screenshot from Inspector*
[image: Screenshot from Inspector]

*Screenshot from Website showing 5 instead of 3 posts/slides*
[image: Screenshot from Swiper showing 5 instead of 3 posts/slides]

*Screenshot from Genesis Featured Post setup*

[image: Screenshot from Genesis Featured Post setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad CSS code.
Everything else works fine.